# LiveData observer does not trigger on a callback

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata

LiveData observer does not trigger when a callback is emitted. But if I put the observable data in a function and change the data it works just fine. Please any ideas what would it be?

```
fun connect(address: String){

    protocolARC.value = ProtocolARC() //OKAY!!!!

    bleManager.gattClient.onCreate(getApplication(), address, object : GattClient.OnCounterReadListener {
        override fun onCounterRead(value: Int) {

            Log.d("HURRAY", "read")

            protocolARC.value = ProtocolARC() //NOT OKAY?????
        }

        override fun onConnected(success: Boolean) {
            stopScan()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a callback. It was not being triggered from the main thread.